# Adding a small png to a larger jpeg/png image using MagickImage 6.9.3 Q16 not working

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I'm basically trying to add a small png (which has some transparent parts) over a much larger jpeg or png file using the composite command in MagickImage.

I've run many different variation of this, with and without geometry arg, but it doesn't seem to work. In the examples below, testt.png would be the same as annotate.png with no sign of black.png.

```
PS C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.3-Q16> composite -geometry +10+0 .\images\black.png .\images\annotate.png testt.png
PS C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.3-Q16> composite -geometry +10+4 .\images\black.png .\images\annotate.png testt.png
```

The strange thing is, if I swap the images meaning I first put the larger image to be applied over the smaller one, I get a weird result where both are visible, but they are completely separate from each other with white space in between.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
# Make a big black thing
convert -size 500x500 xc:black black.png

# Make a red circle on a transparent background
convert -size 100x100 xc:none -fill red -draw "circle 50,50 50,99" transp.png

# Splat circle on background with offset
composite transp.png black.png -geometry +40+120 result.png
```

[image]

Or use `convert` like this for same result:

```
convert black.png transp.png -geometry +40+120 -composite result.png
```

Comment: It works when the image is bigger. I apply the same red circle png to a smaller image (still bigger than the big circle) and it doesn't work. I fixed this by setting the `gravity: center` and then setting the geometry.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to do! What are the sizes of the images, and how do you want to arrange them? *"Adding"* is not a very good word to use - do you maybe mean *"overlaying"* (one on top of the other), or *"abutting"* (side-by-side). Maybe you can give your starting and ending images so I can understand what you want.